# SumAggregation using generics types

Tags: java, generics, sum, aggregate

I want to do a sum for all over a Collection of numbers. But I want to indicate the return number type. For example I want to do the sum of a double collection, but I want to get back an Integer.
I want to have something like this SumAggregator. Here is the code I develop, but I have a Cast problem.

```
public class SumAggregator<N1 extends Number, N2 extends Number> {

    public SumAggregator() {

    }

    public N2 sum(Collection<? extends N1> list){
        Double sum = 0;
        for(Number n : list){
        sum += n.doubleValue();
        }
        return (N2) sum;
    }

}
```

If I want to do `SumAggregator<Double, Double>` I don't have any problem. But if I want to do `SumAggregator<Double, Integer>`, once I run I get the following exception:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

Any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: You cannot. You are blindly casting `N1` to `N2`. You can either hardcode the return type to `int` or return the originally given type.

Comment: Number has methods getInt etc. It may be better and simpler to declare the return type as Number, and then have the caller extract whatever representation is needed.

Comment: Yeah, thanks you Patricia. That is easier, and that was my first approach.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you wanted but you could do something like:

```
interface DoubleConverter<N extends Number) {
    N2 convert(double d);
}
```

And add a constructor to your SumAggregator:

```
private final DoubleConverter<N2> converter;
public SumAggregator(DoubleConverter<N2> converter) {
    this.converter = converter;
}
```

And your method would look like:

```
public N2 sum(Collection<? extends N1> list){
    double sum = 0;
    for(Number n : list){
        sum += n.doubleValue();
    }
    return converter.convert(sum);
}
```

finally, you would create one with:

```
SumAggregator<Double, Integer> a = new SumAggregator<> (new DoubleConverter<Integer>() {
    public Integer convert(double d) { return (int) d; }
});
```

Finally, you could add some helper methods in the DoubleConverter interface:

```
DoubleConverter<Integer> INTEGER = new DoubleConverter<Integer>() {
    public Integer convert(double d) { return (int) d; }
}
```

so the calling code can use:

```
SumAggregator<Double, Integer> a = new SumAggregator<> (DoubleConverter.INTEGER);
```

Comment: But reading my answer, I concur with Patricia Shanahan's comment: it would be much simpler to just return a double and let the calling code convert to whatever it needs.

Comment: very nice solution. It is not what I want, but it's good. Thanks

Comment: I changed DoubleConverter to NumberConverter. And of course the sum to return Number rather than Double. Then I use d.doubleValue(), d.intValue(), etc. for the conversion (I prefer that to a cast).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I choose:

```
public class SumAggregator<N1 extends Number, N2 extends Number> {

    private final NumberConverter<N2> converter;

    public SumAggregator(NumberConverter<N2> converter) {
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    public N2 sum(Collection<? extends N1> list){
        double sum = 0;
        for(Number n : list){
            sum += n.doubleValue();
        }
        return converter.convert(sum);
    }

}
```

And then:

```
public interface NumberConverter<N2> {

    N2 convert(Number d);

    NumberConverter<Short> SHORT = new NumberConverter<Short>() {
        public Short convert(Number d) { 
            return d.shortValue(); 
        }
    };

    NumberConverter<Integer> INTEGER = new NumberConverter<Integer>() {
        public Integer convert(Number d) { 
            return d.intValue(); 
        }
    };

    NumberConverter<Double> DOUBLE = new NumberConverter<Double>() {
        public Double convert(Number d) { 
            return d.doubleValue(); 
        }
    };

    NumberConverter<Float> FLOAT = new NumberConverter<Float>() {
        public Float convert(Number d) { 
            return d.floatValue(); 
        }
    };

    NumberConverter<Long> LONG = new NumberConverter<Long>() {
        public Long convert(Number d) { 
            return d.longValue(); 
        }
    };

}
```